# Mapping vector to function in Simulation

Tags: r

When simulating 10 sets of normally distributed numbers, the first two ways are clear to understand. In the first one, `rnorm` is taking `1:10` as means. But in the third one, what function `1:10` is doing? is it simply replicating map 10 times? In `map2` what are the first and second `1:10` will do. Any help?

```r
library(tidyverse)
map(1:10, ~ rnorm(10, .)) %>% map_dbl(mean)
#>  [1] 1.228481 1.598655 3.390027 3.881330 4.981230 5.534035 6.838245 7.690397
#>  [9] 7.969407 9.461679
rerun(10, rnorm(10)) %>% map_dbl(mean)
#>  [1]  0.10263879 -0.15584495  0.14294670  0.05466051  0.43497316  0.30814623
#>  [7] -0.13173104  0.47359807 -0.33331884 -0.49655876

#doubtful
map(1:10, ~ rnorm(10)) %>% map_dbl(mean)
#>  [1]  0.09157949  0.17883133  0.06443145  0.15372693  0.29376735  0.50717543
#>  [7] -0.41395627  0.15125954  0.19700380  0.21262708
map2(1:10, 1:10, ~rnorm(10, .)) %>% map_dbl(mean)
#>  [1]  0.9173579  1.7272657  2.4175854  4.2008470  4.5153217  6.5849078
#>  [7]  7.0574423  8.4102611  9.2362719 10.0684648
```

Comment: The third is just replicating `rnorm(10)` ten times as the `.x` argument is unused.  The fourth is equivalent to the first as the `.y` argument is unused.

Comment: But in the following ```map2(16:25, 1:10, ~rnorm(10, .)) %>% map_dbl(mean)``` I am getting means from 16 to 25. So the ```1:10``` has some functionality I feel.  It is supplying means to ```rnorm``` and second ```1:10``` is replicating. I never know ```map``` is used for replications.

Comment: @RamakrishnaS try `map2(.x = 16:25, .y = 1:10, ~rnorm(n = .y, mean = .x))` and you should get a clearer idea of what is going on. If you don't use `.y`, then `map2` isn't using the second argument.

Comment: @AllanCameron I tried your approach but this code is generating different number of means from 1 to 10.  i.e., first simulation has only 1 means, second has 2 so on. ```map2(.x = 16:25, .y = 1:10, ~rnorm(10, mean = .x))``` this is giving desired result, but I don't know where the ```.y``` is used. It is just used for replication I think.

Comment: @RamakrishnaS yes, the code I suggested was not a replacement for yours, but a way to understand what map2 does and how it works